# Printer prints blank pages

Tags: printing

I have a new Brother HL-2240 printer usb connected on Ubuntu 14.04.1. using the Brother HL-2170W Foomatic/ljet4 driver (the driver recommended by default). I tried printing pdf files from document viewer, files from abiword and Firefox but it only prints out blank pages.

From CUPS:

```
Description: Brother HL-2240 series
Location:   bill-Unknow
Driver: Brother HL-2170W Foomatic/ljet4 (grayscale, 2-sided printing)
Connection: usb://Brother/HL-2240%20series?serial=E4N263380
Defaults:   job-sheets=none, none media=na_letter_8.5x11in sides=one-sided
```

Answer (score 3):

Mine started doing the same thing and the self test page is also blank. To fix it:

1. Press the "go" button on the printer three times. If the test
   page prints ok it is your driver.
2. Ubuntu software center - search for hpijs - install it all.
3. Remove the printer - add it back
4. Use the Brother HL-2170W Foomatic/hpijs-pcl5e driver
5. Printer works now.