# Brother HL-1202 prints blank pages

Tags: drivers, printing

The printer Brother HL-1202 does not work properly. With the default installation it does not work at all.

To fix it I followed the instructions in
[Printer prints blank pages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527741/printer-prints-blank-pages), in particular: "Use the Brother HL-2170W Foomatic/hpijs-pcl5e driver". With that driver the printer manage to print blank pages, but no ink is printed in the pages at all. That occurs either for a test page or a print from a pdf file using adobe acrobat for instance.

The self-print page test works properly and information is printed in the page (so the toner is correctly installed).

I tried with many other hpijs-pcl5e drivers visible from other HL-XXXX printer drivers that appear in the installation options, all of them produce blank pages.

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Because the driver of this model is built for i386 and you are running on 64bit (amd64) then firstly you need install 32bit (i386) library via:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Now you can install driver normally by downloading driver from Brother website for HL-1200/ 1201/ 1211W at http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=as_ot&lang=en&prod=hl1211w_as&os=128.

Alternatively, select Drive from Ubuntu driver database for this model.

Comment: This fixed the insanity with my HL-L2390DW printer as well. I downloaded the drivers from a similar link in the brothers website, and it only worked after a reboot and the commands above.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my brother printer HL-1222WE. Printed pages was blank. It was happend when i used common driver from ubuntu 18.04. 
Now is fine after I installed a driver by using Driver Install Tool, got it from support.brother.com

Comment: As it says @wo-pe try to install the drivers from here : https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=mx&lang=es&prod=hl1202_us&os=128&flang=English